# Vee-validate returns always true

Tags: vuejs2

I have 2 fields to validate but always returns true in the method validateBeforeSubmit() after i submit.

Whitout button submit it works nice and returns errors.first(name) in the good language

What do i do wrong?

App.vue:

```
<form @submit.prevent="validateBeforeSubmit">

    <form-input v-on:input="handleTitle" :validate="'required|email'" label="email" labelvalue="email" type="text" placeholder="" name="email" :value="title" classname="form-control" id=""></form-input>
    <form-input v-on:input="handleLink" :validate="'required'" label="Link" labelvalue="Link" type="text" placeholder="" name="link" :value="link" classname="form-control" id=""></form-input>

methods: {
        validateBeforeSubmit() {
            this.$validator.validateAll().then((result) => {
                if (result) {
                    // eslint-disable-next-line
                    alert('Form Submitted!');
                    return;
                }

                alert('Correct them errors!');
            });
        },
```

Input.vue:

```
<template>
     <div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <span>{{ errors.first(name) }}</span>
            <label v-if="label" :for="label" v-html="labelvalue"></label>
            <input v-validate="validate" v-on:input="updateValue($event)" :type="type" :placeholder="placeholder" :name="name" :value="value" :class="classname" :id="id">
        </div>
     </div>
</template>

export default {
    props: {
        validate: String,
        type: String,
        placeholder: String,
        name: String,
        value: String,
        classname: String,
        id: String,
        label: String,
        labelvalue: String
    },
    methods: {
        updateValue: function (evt) {
            this.$emit('input', evt)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`validateAll` does not look into the child component. You have to inject parent validator. Add `inject: ['$validator']` in `Input.vue` file. It should solve the problem. The export block will look like this

```
export default {
    inject: ['$validator'],
    props: {
        validate: String,
        type: String,
        placeholder: String,
        name: String,
        value: String,
        classname: String,
        id: String,
        label: String,
        labelvalue: String
    },
    methods: {
        updateValue: function (evt) {
            this.$emit('input', evt)
        }
    }
}
```

For more informatin about `inject` you can look into [this reference](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/advanced/#injection)